# Are early morning suburban commuter trains crowded in Chennai

Tags: airport-transfer, chennai

I am travelling to Chennai in a couple of months time. I have booked a ticket from Frankfurt to Chennai in Lufthansa. This means I arrive at close to midnight in Chennai. I googled and discovered that there exists a suburban train system close to Chennai airport which takes me to the two big railway stations in Chennai (Egmor and Centraal). I plan to take a commuter train at 04:00 AM. I will have with me 2 big suitcases (though they will not be more than 5-10kgs each).

I have a few questions:

1. How much of a walk is it from Chennai International arrivals area to the nearest suburban railway station?
2. How crowded will be the train?
3. If I wish to purchase a "First class ticket", how much will it cost? Will there be an open ticket counter at 04 AM? Is there a mobile App where I can purchase before hand?

Answer (score 5):

1) Probably 5-10 minutes walk, considering your luggage. The station is visible from the airport. There is a subway connecting to the airport to cross the highway.

2) More or less empty. Minimal traffic at the best. You can easily get a seat. [The timetable for reference](http://www.sr.indianrailways.gov.in/view_section.jsp?lang=0&id=0,2,1429). You check the route from Tambaram to Chennai Beach to go to the railway station.

3) I don't know the cost, but not worth it. The seats probably have a bit of a cushion and that is it.

This is from when I used it maybe 6-7 years ago.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see that I can board the train at a station called Thirusulam. But any idea if the counter which sells the ticket will be open at 0400? I don't think I can expect automatic ticket machines yet in Indian train stations.

Comment: @DarthVader The higher probability is it will be open(ticket offices are always open in India when trains are running, though not sure for local trains), but I am taking a guess. Somebody who has used so early in the morning might be a good person to confirm.